# Prove that there exist no element of order 18 in $S_9$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Prove that there exist no element of order 18 in $S_9$.

How do I prove this ? I think the idea is that elements of the form: $(123456)(789)$ have order 6 as $\text{lcm}(6,3)=6$. Elements of the form $(123456789)(10\,11)$ surely don't exist in $S_9$. And I don't see any other ways to get to order 18. How do I prove this rigoursly ?

Comment: An idea would be to first try to find a general statement of the special cases you mentioned. Ie, given a decomposition into disjoint cycles, what is the order of a permutation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems you already know that the order is the least common multiple of the cycle lengths. For the least common multiple of a set of numbers to be $2\cdot3^2$, at least one of the numbers must include a factor $3^2$ – but the only partition of $9$ with that property is the one with a single part $9$, and in this case the order is $9$, not $18$.

Answer (score 1):

An element $\sigma$ of $\mathfrak{S}_9$ gives a [partition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28number_theory%29) of $9$, and $\text{ord}(\sigma)$ is the lcm of the elements of the partition. If $\text{ord}(\sigma)=18$, the partition contains a multiple of $2$ and of $3$; you can check that the lcm associated to such a partition is never $18$. (There are only five partitions satisfying this condition.)